# Fix Bootstrap Padding On Nested Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 applies a 15px left and right padding on columns.

This is causing me trouble because my layout has a lot of nested columns:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-6"></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aeup8/1/).

I don't need to just remove the padding because I need the separation between the elements.

The result I'm after, visually, is this: http://jsfiddle.net/Aeup8/8/

My first approach was to set:

```
[class^='col-'] {
    padding:0;
}
[class^='col-'] + [class^='col-'] {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

However, this will not fix columns that wrap onto a second row.

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aeup8/2/)

My second approach was using JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
    var $els = $('[class^="col-"');
    //console.log($els);
    var cols = {};
    $els.each(function(i, col) {
        var classes = $(col).attr('class').split(' ');

        classes.forEach(function(str) {
            var match = str.match(/col-(\w+)-(\d+)/);
            if ( match ) {
                //console.log($els.eq(i));
                cols[match[1]] = cols[match[1]] || {};
                var current = cols[match[1]];

                if ( match[2] == 12 ) {
                    current.ids = [];
                    current.sum = 0;

                    $els.eq(i).css({ padding: 0 });
                    return
                }

                current.ids = current.ids || [];
                current.sum = current.sum || 0;
                current.sum += ( +match[2] );
                current.ids.push(i);
                if (current.sum == 12) {
                    //console.log(current);
                    current.ids.forEach(function(id) {
                        $els.eq(id).css({ 'padding': 0, 'padding-right': '15px' });
                        if (id == i) $els.eq(id).css({ 'padding': 0, 'padding-left': '15px' });
                    });
                    current.ids = [];
                    current.sum = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aeup8/4/)

But it has problems:

- It does not traverse the DOM in the desired order, so it won't do nested ones well.
- I don't even want to fix that because it seems like this is a very bad solution (it would happen every time the viewport size changes)

What do I do?

Answer (score 46):

You can counter the duplicated padding when [nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) by wrapping each layer in its own `.row`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The gap between the 2 primary columns will remain, but the nesting won't continue to indent further: http://jsfiddle.net/5uqmE/.

[They currently accomplish this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/less/grid.less#L35-L41) by [apply a negative `margin`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/less/mixins.less#L646-L651) that opposes the outer `padding`:

```
// Row
//
// Rows contain and clear the floats of your columns.

.row {
  .make-row();
}
```

```
// Creates a wrapper for a series of columns
.make-row(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  margin-left:  (@gutter / -2);
  margin-right: (@gutter / -2);
  &:extend(.clearfix all);
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, however, this is actually a very complicated layout generated from WP widgets that change positions on different screen sizes, and making this change is actually very difficult. There has to be a way to do it without using the .row wrappers!, but in any case, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Alain Jacomet Forte If this is a complicated layout, why are you using  Bootstrap in the first place? Maintainers of your code would rely on Bootrstap layout rather then overridden custom grid. It is a bad practice to override behaviour of the framework.

Answer (score 10):

On your container

```
.row  .row {
    margin: 0px -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple css based solution can be creating custom classes and applying them to col-* for clearing paddings on inner divs or where you do not want padding.

```
<div class="col-md-6 mmLR15"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 mM15"></div>
<div class="col-md-12 mM15">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mmR15">
        <div class="col-md-12 mm15"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 mm15"></div>
      </div><!-- col-md-6 -->
      <div class="col-md-6 mmL15"></div>
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- col-md-12 -->
```

Now for mmLR15, mmR15, mmL15 is to clear the bootstrap columns padding where needed. Below have written classes declaration to help you understand my point clearly.

```
.mmLR15 {
  margin: 0px -15px;
}
.mmR15 {
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.mmL15 {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

This will only clear bootstrap classes on div you don't want. Have to include class where needed. You can create a separate file and include after bootstrap so your code is cleaner. mmR15 & mmL15 are only for div's in row as row clears left and right margin.

For media break points where bootstrap makes columns 100% you can reset them depending upon ur need or should I say upon you layout. Hope this helps you.