# Bootstrap 3 remove padding on all sides for nested columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to remove padding on nested columns, including top and bottom padding, without adding new classes for it.

I tried this article: [Fix Bootstrap Padding On Nested Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748673/fix-bootstrap-padding-on-nested-columns) - it says to wrap a `<div class="row">` around what i want to remove padding on, but it only works for left/right padding, not ALL padding.

Any tips, besides coming up with my own "noPadding" class to apply to those ones i need no padding on?

Comment: `col`'s in bootstrap don't have any vertical padding

Comment: Use the F12 feature on your browser to find where the padding is coming from. Then you should be able to modify the CSS accordingly. Noting @3rror404 's comment above.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a wildcard CSS selector to accomplish what you want so that you wouldn't have to tag all of the inner cols with a special class.

```
.row > div[class*="col-"] > .row > div[class*="col-"] {

  padding:0;

}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/TgzHyfdeoD

Comment: I only learned about wildcard css selectors, and think they're awesome! But, I don't understand what's going on with this one - why does the whole thing appear to be duplicated within the class?

Comment: Because we only want to select inner/nested `col-*`s, not the first level ones.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it'd interfere with bootstrap, but a lil jQuery goes a long way.

Try something like this this and see what happens:

```js
$('#outerContainer').find('*').css('padding', '0');
```

Comment: Minus 1 for supplying a JS solution to a CSS question.